# Have button appear with icon only in responsive mode. (html/css/materialize)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, materialize

**How can i have a button lose it's text but not it's icon when viewing on a mobile advice?**

For example when it shows a face icon by MaterializeCSS and the text **"support"**, I want it to remove the text but still show the icon so the button becomes smaller in size. I use the MaterializeCSS framework and the Materialize icons.

**The button looks like this in html:**

`<a class="waves-effect waves-light white-text top-button z-depth-2">
  <i class="material-icons left">
    face
  </i>
    Contact support
 </a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light white-text top-button z-depth-2">
   <i class="material-icons left">
      face
   </i>
     <span class="hide-on-small-only"> Contact support </span>
</a>
```

You need to add span tag with hide-on-small-only class from materialize to hide button text on mobile only.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! One question though, on desktop size the button text and icon are centered nicely, but when viewing on mobile the icon is slightly off center to the left. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Welcome. I think that class `left` used in i tag makes it left, try `center` instead. Kindly upvote also. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I tried to upvote you but I cant since i have less than 15 rep haha. Sorry!

Comment: No problem. You'll soon be in that elite category of up voting haha. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

Use `media query` on mobile like this .

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .top-button {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  .top-button i {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

**Here is the working code**

```css
.top-button {
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .top-button {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  .top-button i {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="waves-effect waves-light white-text top-button z-depth-2"><i class="material-icons left">face</i>Contact support</a>
```